# how to solve "libsvm classes are not in classpath" in weka? show me with picture please

Tags: svm, weka

I'M using weka 3.6.9 & libsvm or liblinear shows "libsvm classes are not in classpath" can you please sho with picture to me how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to use Weka 3.8.x or 3.9.x, as you can use its package manager. Below are instructions for both.

**Weka 3.6.9**

- Download the libsvm zip file from the [libsvm project page](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/)
- Decompress the archive
- Copy `libsvm.jar` from inside the `java` directory into the directory where your `weka.jar` is located
- Open a terminal and go to the directory where your `weka.jar` is located
- Start Weka like this on Linux (under Windows, use `;` instead of `:`):

  ```
  java -cp weka.jar:libsvm.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser
  ```
- Use the `weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM` classifier

**Weka 3.8.x/3.9.x**

- Open the package manager
- Search for `libsvm`
- Install the `libSVM` package
- Restart Weka and use the `weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM` classifier